# Why I get double free?

Tags: c, double-free

Here is my code. I  try to malloc the element that been malloc, and I don't know how to free them.

```
char *d = "apple";
int main() {            
  char *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  char **b = &a;
  strcpy(a,d);
  printf("%c", *b[0]);
  b[0] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
  free(b[0]);
  free(a);
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: I add my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
char **b = &a;
```

`b[0]` is the same as `a`. So when you do

```
b[0] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

you're replacing the value of `a` with this new allocation.

Then `free(b[0])` is the same as `free(a);`. So if you do both of these, you're freeing the same memory twice, which is a double free.

You've also leaked the original allocation that was assigned to `a`, since you no longer have a pointer to that. You need another variable to save that, so you can free it.

```
char *d = "apple";
int main() {            
  char *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  char **b = &a;
  strcpy(a,d);
  printf("%c", *b[0]);
  char *c = a; // save a before overwriting it below
  b[0] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
  free(b[0]);
  free(c);
}
```

Comment: but if I delete
free(b[0])
it will tell me that I have memory leak.

Comment: I explained that in my answer, didn't I? Read the last paragraph.